# Force ST_collect to return only a GeometryCollection

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometrycollection

In the postgis documentation it is mentioned that *ST_collect* returns a MULTI* or a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION. But how can I force the function to only return a GeometryCollection not depending on it's input argument.

**For Example:** I have a postgreSQL database with a column of type GeometryCollection. And it should store geometries which a user has drawn. This can by any combination of geometries of points, lines, polygons etc...  If the combination is a point, a line and a polygon ST_collect returns a GeometryCollection. But if the combination is two polygons it returns a MultiPolygon. Is it possible that ST_collect returns only GeometryCollections even if the input is a single polygon?

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Collect(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>'geometry')))
FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements('{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{

         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     14.845962524414062,
                     46.96830518448586
                  ],
                  [
                     14.845962524414062,
                     47.02309964439266
                  ],
                  [
                     14.976425170898438,
                     47.02309964439266
                  ],
                  [
                     14.976425170898438,
                     46.96830518448586
                  ],
                  [
                     14.845962524414062,
                     46.96830518448586
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}'::json->'features') AS feat
) as f;
```

Comment: Perhaps just cast it to a geometry collection?

Comment: Why, as a matter of interest? GeometryColllections are something of a pain to work with.

Comment: Yes you are right John. But i only wanna know if there is a possibillity.. Only for interest :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ST_ForceCollection http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_Collection.html

A simple example with point geometry:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ForceCollection(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 1)')));
```

Result:

```
"GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 1))"
```

Comment: omg how i couldn see that in the docs.
Thanks for helping :)